# How do I interprete a sequence of => in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm currently starting with play framework, but my Scala knowledge is not sufficient.

As I know the => indicates that IsAuthenticated has some kind of functions as parameter.
I found out as well the f: => String... is a function with no input value. But how do I interprete the complete line with its 3 => ?
And further down, what exactly happens in the second line with => f(user)(request)? What is the target function for user and request object?

```
  def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
    Action(request => f(user)(request))
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=> String => Request[AnyContent] => Result
```

is easier to read with parens added:

```
=> (String => (Request[AnyContent] => Result))
```

You can try this in the REPL. For example:

```
scala> def foo(f: => String => Int => Char): Char = f("abcdefgh")(4)
foo: (f: => String => (Int => Char))Char
```

In this example, *f* is a <s>nullary function</s> call-by-name parameter that returns a function (let's call that function *g*). *g* is a function that accepts a String parameter and returns yet another function (*h*). *h* is a function that accepts an Int parameter and returns a Char.

Example invocation:

```
scala> foo { s: String => { i: Int => s.charAt(i) } }
res0: Char = e
```

Let's walk through the type of each expression in the method body as it's evaluated:

- `f`

  - Type: `String => (Int => Char)`
  - Value: `{ s: String => { i: Int => s.charAt(i) } }`
- `f("abcdefgh")`

  - Type: `Int => Char`
  - Value: `{ i: Int => "abcdefgh".charAt(i) }`
- `f("abcdefgh")(4)`

  - Type: `Char`
  - Value: `'e'`

Comment: It's called `call by name` (`by name parameter`), not `nullary function`.

Comment: And how would I call foo in your example? What kind of function would fit the foo signature? And what is the first => good for?

Comment: @senia What's the difference?

Comment: @be_mi Updated my answer to include an invocation. Like senia said, the leading => makes it a call-by-name parameter, which means that the expression you provide at the call site won't be evaluated until foo uses it.

Comment: @ChristopherMartin: difference is on the caller-side - you don't have to create function explicitly. And the most significant difference is: [call by name](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[scala]+call+by+name) vs [nullary function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[scala]+nullary+function).

Answer (score 0):

A couple of additions to the accepted answer

1. About `Security.Authenticated`

   Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
      Action(request => f(user)(request))
   }

   Security.Authenticated - seems to be a function that takes two lists of parameters. The first list of parameters:

   ```
   (username:String, onUnauthorized:Boolean)
   ```

   and the second list is one argument:

   ```
   (g:User => Action)
   ```

   The complete signature can be something like:

   ```
   def Authenticated(username:String, onUnauthorized:Boolean)(g:User => Action)
   ```
2. `Action` seems to be a class that takes a function in it's constructor:

   ```
   class Action(h:Request => Result)
   ```

   The argument to the constructor is a new function

   ```
   def hActual(request:Request):Result = f(user)(request)
   ```

   > (the `def` should have `user` in the scope, because it is not given in arguments. For instance, `hActual` can be declared immediately before `Action` constructor call:
   >
   > ```
   > def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
   >     def hActual(request:Request):Result = f(user)(request)
   >     Action(hActual)
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > )
3. Also It seems so that the constructor can be called using curring:

   ```
   def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
       Action(f(user))
   }
   ```